# Pass specific data from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list. What I want is when I click on one of the item of List a new page should open where the data related to only that listItem is displayed. Right now I am using anchor tag and .config to pass data like this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <a href="#detail/{{field.firstName}}/{{field.personNo}}/{{field.street}}/{{field.city}}/{{field.postcode}}" id="a-item"> <div style="width:100%;height:100%" >    
         {{field.firstName}}<br>
         {{field.personNo}} </div></a> 
 </ion-item>
```

And

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/mainpage.html'

  }).
  when('/detail/:name/:no/:street/:city/:postcode', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/details.html',
    controller: 'detailctrl'
})
}])
```

I don't think this is an effective way to pass data. Although I know about .service but I can't figure out a way to pass data specific to the item clicked.  Please suggest a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is the classic master detail pattern that you indeed would want to use a service (or factory) for.

First change I'll make to your code is giving the main route a controller, as well as for the details route only passing in the personNo.

```
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/mainpage.html',
        controller: 'mainctrl'
      }).
      when('/detail/:no', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/details.html',
        controller: 'detailctrl'
    })
}])
```

Next, let's set up a "PeopleService" via a factory with two methods. One, is the GetPeople method which gets all the people in an array and resolves a promise via $http before storing it in a private variable. The GetPerson method looks up a person by personNo in that private variable.

```
.factory('PeopleService',['$http',function($http){
    var people = [];
    return {
        GetPeople: function(){ 
            $http.get("path/to/resource").then(function(response){
                people = response;
                return response;
            });
        },
        GetPerson: function(personNo){
            for(i=0;i<people.length;i++){
                if(people[i].personNo == personNo){
                    return people[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Next, in our mainctrl we will want to call that GetPeople function.

```
.controller("mainctrl",['PeopleService',function(PeopleService){
    PeopleService.GetPeople().then(function(people){
        $scope.people = people;
    });
}]);
```

Finally, in our detailsctrl, we will get the personNo from the $routeParams and use it to call the GetPerson method from our service.

```
.controller("detailctrl",['$routeParams','PeopleService',function($routeParams,PeopleService){
    var personNo = $routeParams.no;
    $scope.person = PeopleService.GetPerson(personNo);
}]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What happens if the user deep links into the detail view? I believe it'll throw an error, since the AJAX request has never been made...